# Setting border type for opencv c++ function: erode()

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, border

I need to apply OpenCV functions `dilate()` and `erode()` to a `Mat` object which is in fact an ROI within a bigger image. `Mat roiImg`  is generated by creating a header for an ROI inside the original image `img`:

```
Mat img = imread(...);
Mat roiImg = img (Rect(...));
```

This is the list of arguments for `erode()`:

```
void erode(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray kernel, Pointanchor=Point(-1,-1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue() )
```

The problem is that since my input image to functions erode/dilate is a header for an ROI, it seems that choosing `BORDER_CONSTANT` as the border type along with the border value equal to `morphologyDefaultBorderValue()` doesn't have any impact and the border values are obtained from the original image.

Then I found this in the documentation for `copyMakeBorder()`:

> When the source image is a part (ROI) of a bigger image, the function will try to use the pixels outside of the ROI to form a border. To disable this feature and always do extrapolation, as if `src` was not a ROI, use borderType | `BORDER_ISOLATED`.

However, `cv::borderInterpolate()` which is the function called from within `erode()` function, doesn't accept `BORDER_ISOLATED` as a valid border type!

For now, to get around this problem, I have to clone `roiImg`, and then call `erode()`. But ideally I do not want the overhead of cloning. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2598) in OpenCV. Until it's fixed, cloning might be the best workaround.

Comment: The link is dead